# (kind of) Singleton Pattern in Python using Hash and `==`

Tags: python, hash, singleton

I am looking into ways to use a quasi Singleton Pattern in python. Quick problem description:

I have objects that describe subset of a certain group. For simplicity assume integer numbers like in `set([1,2,3])`. In my case, comparison is difficult and if possible expensive, so I assume that if I have

```
complex_set1 = ...
complex_set2 = ...
```

these are different. Also, all set are immutable (like frozenset). Except there exists the full and empty sets for convenience

```
full_set = FullSet()
empty_set = EmptySet()
```

These seem to make sense to be singletons. One way would be to create one instance and just add it to the package *on import*. So that there exists only one and you cannot create another.

Now my idea:

Since I do not care if I have multiple objects as long as they are considered the same in any case (besides `a is b` is obviously false) I just make them look equal (like a singleton would). An example would be

```
len(set([FullSet(), FullSet()]))
>>> 1
```

So, I experimented with

```
def hash(self):
    return 0  # make sure all have the same hash

def __eq__(self, other):
    if is instance(other, FullSet):
        return True

    return NotImplemented
```

Does this have a name? Is it considered a singleton pattern or something else?
Should I use this or are there caveats to be aware of?

Any comments on the hash value which is also used for other purposes than comparison? Does it make more sense to use e.g. `return hash(FullSet)`

Comment: Correct Python syntax: `isinstance(other, FullSet)`. I can't think of a name for this pattern. The alternative is to give both classes a `__new__` method that returns the one instance that is created on first call. In other words, just make it a real singleton, at which point the default `__eq__` and `__hash__` implementations will work and you don't have to worry about naming or correctness of implementation.

Comment: Note that in this case I might use `return hash(FullSet)` (the hash of the class) to produce a more 'interesting' hash and not trivially cluster around slot `0` in the hash table. No, `return hash(FullSet())` would not work, because then you'd recursively invoke `FullSet.__hash__`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with `FullSet()` and `FullSet`. My mistake in `isinstance` and `hash`. I wanted to use the class, not an instance.